# Axon Server - send events when the application starts

Tags: event-sourcing, axon

My situation is as follows:
I have two microservices. When the first emits an event, the other correctly receives it;
If the first emits an event and the second microservice is off, when I turn on the second microservice, it does not receive the event.

edit:
I'm trying saga, when I issue a command I get it on the second service only if it is on.
the error I get is:

```
2020-04-06 13:53:40.341  WARN 1188 --- [-worker-ELG-3-1] i.a.a.message.command.C
ommandDispatcher  : No Handler for command: com.progressivecoder.ecommerce.comma
nds.CreateInvoiceCommand
2020-04-06 13:54:38.707  WARN 1188 --- [nio-8024-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandler
ExceptionResolver : Async request timed out
2020-04-06 13:54:41.514  WARN 1188 --- [nio-8024-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandler
ExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.Asyn
cRequestTimeoutException]
2020-04-06 13:55:01.699  WARN 1188 --- [nio-8024-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandler
ExceptionResolver : Async request timed out
2020-04-06 13:55:01.700  WARN 1188 --- [nio-8024-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandler
ExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.Asyn
cRequestTimeoutException]
```

reading the guide, I realized that I have to configure the command bus to work in asynchronous;
is there an example from which I can get ideas?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Axon Server do you see the event that you emitted when you run a query in the search tab? Do you see the second microservice in the overview tab and does it show the tracking event processor in the application details?

Marc